# Show message only on first access to the web page in c#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

With this code I show `JavaScript` alert message box in `ASP.Net` from server side using `C#`.

But I need show the message only on first access to the web page, how to do resolve this ?

Please help me.

My code below, thank you in advance.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string message = "Hello!";
  System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
  sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>");
  sb.Append("window.onload=function(){");
  sb.Append("alert('");
  sb.Append(message);
  sb.Append("')};");
  sb.Append("</script>");
  ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "alert", sb.ToString());
}
```

Comment: You can check if the page is not postback then show the message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check that the page is not posting back before you display your alert:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
      {
        string message = "Hello!";
        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>");
        sb.Append("window.onload=function(){");
        sb.Append("alert('");
        sb.Append(message);
        sb.Append("')};");
        sb.Append("</script>");
        ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "alert", sb.ToString());
      }
```

**Updates:**

You can create a cookie to track the alert so it does not display after displaying during the initial page load:

```
private bool Alerted()
{
    if (Request.Cookies["alerted"] != null)
         return Server.HtmlEncode(Request.Cookies["alerted"].Value) == "true";
    else
    {
       Response.Cookies["alerted"].Value = "true";
       Response.Cookies["alerted"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(10);
       return false;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
if(!Alerted())
{
   // alert script here
}
```

Comment: Thank you for reply, but I don't have change; the message is showed for each single access.